# htaccess won't redirect properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Currently i'm working on a backend website admin but i have some trouble with redirecting. The issue is this when someone wants to edit a specific job function he needs to be redirected to for example: jobs/edit/Webdeveloper and in the PHP script it will send in an action to go to the edit page but when i redirecting it, it stays on the same page and does a simply refresh.

This is what i have as an link tag:

```
<a href='".$adminurl."/jobs/edit/".$list["function"]."'>Change</a>
```

And it works out like this **domain.com/admin/jobs/edit/Webdeveloper**

This is what i have in my .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^jobs/change/(.*) jobs.php?&action=change&job=$1
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Try adding last rule. `RewriteRule ^jobs/change/(.*) jobs.php?action=change&job=$1 [L]`. Ampersand after question mark should be removed.

Comment: What does the [L] stand for?

Comment: This is the [Last rule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html). This means, when this condition is met, exit the .htaccess and don't apply more rules that are following.

Comment: Well i did everything but it still doesn't work ofcourse after this rule more rules follow so i cannot exit the .htaccess yet. it still refreshes the page i have this rule set for a other link tag with the same attributes in it and it works fine so i don't understand why this one doesn't.

Comment: Edit on comment: i found the issue it was that the if and else wasn't set properly i set ``if($action == "change") { } else { }`` and it should've been: ``$_GET["action"] == "change")`` i think because he doesn't know where to get the $action so thats why it just refreshed the page (i'm not sure if it's true and please correct me if it's not)